# python, add vertex group to modifier

Tags: python, modifiers, vertex-groups

i want to add a vertex group by it's name (vgroup22) to a surface deform modifier.
the code should look kinda like this:

```
bpy.data.objects['Body.p.2'].modifiers["Surface Deform"].vertex_group ??????
```

thx for taking a look

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it in the answer box below instead of adding it to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution (blender 2.83.3)

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Surface Deform"].vertex_group = "vgroup22"
```

didn't know, that every action is displayed in the "info" window and the code can simply be copied.